# Independent managed resources in Solr standalone with the same configSet

Tags: solr

I have been using Solr for sometime now (currently using 8.2.0), always in stand-alone mode. I am trying to use synonyms as a managed resource, and what I have found is that all cores that share a given configset share the synonyms. In fact, digging a bit deeper it seems that the configuration is not replicated upon core creation, only referenced, so it is in fact using the same file for all the cores (_schema_analysis_synonyms_english.json in this case).

I would like to *define* the core configuration once, as I will be using many cores with the same parameters, but I want them to handle synonyms and protected words *independently*. I know that I can manually copy the contents of the configset to the core directory, but this option is too cumbersome as it involves meddling with the file system and it may not scale well, and that if there is access to the Solr server at all.

I have tried some options, such as using `<str name="shareSchema">${shareSchema:false}</str>`
in `/var/solr/data/solr.xml`, yet to no avail.

Can I expect to be there any way to provide this functionality for a core created through the CREATE REST API? If I have to consider moving to Solr cloud mode, would this behaviour be there as well or the one I want to achieve?

Thanks,

Comment: In cloud mode you can use the configset api and create a new configset based from an old one: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/configsets-api.html#configsets-create - I don't think there's a way around making explicit copies from the configset directory if you're using Solr in standalone mode (you could have a master config that encapsulates all necessary fields and add core-specific fields and types instead with a prefix, but that will leave you with one large configset).

Comment: Creating a new configset from a previously defined one would not be an issue as long as it can be done through the API. If that is the case then moving to cloud mode could be a valid solution worth testing. Thanks, @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another option which works nicely in standalone mode, which involves using environment variables in the `solrconfig.xml` within `<configset dir>/conf/`.

If I manually set `storageDir` for the managed resources content I can force a different directory per core:

```
    <restManager>
        <str name="storageDir">/var/solr/data/${solr.core.name}/managed_resources</str>
    </restManager>
```

I guess that something better than `/var/solr/data/${solr.core.name}` can be used to refer to the core directory, but I have not found it yet.